# Installed Windows on Large Partition Affects Performance

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I dont know whats happening if I install Windows 7 on my 750GB Hard Drive the startup takes about 10mins.
But when I partition my drive and give 400GB or lower for the Windows Installation The Startup is fast. I just need more disk space for my Windows but I cant do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 v1511 SDK: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771 which is the last version that works in Win7), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **CPU Usage**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Boot**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This reboots Windows and captures all activity during boot. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0.Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file (to reduce size), upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: do this for both setups (750 and 400GB) and share both files, so that I can compare them

Comment: have you captured the 2 traces? or do you need help?

Comment: Hi Sorry, I was not able to reply I found out that the drive was failing so I immediately replace it with new one.

Comment: ok, post this as answer.